# Change the number of workspaces shown in the workspace switcher in the Unity sidebar

Tags: unity, launcher, workspace-switcher

I just increased the number of workspaces with CompizConfig from 4 to 6 and all was fine, but then I noticed that the workspace switcher in Unity's launcher still only showed 4 workspaces and it stopped updating which workspace I was working in. It is not that it prevents me from working, it just annoys that it isn't coherent with the number of workspaces I actually use.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not doable. There have been questions before and I've not seen them answered

Answer (score 0):

While maybe not impossible it would be quite a bit to do based on how it currently works and implemented, plus any changes have to be compiled in.

1. It is set to only work on 2x2 Ws setup, on any other you'll just get the default icon. (- workspace-switcher-top-left icon
2. Based on viewport position what you see is another icon, not 1 icon dynamically changing, there are 4 icons available for use. So for more than 4 Ws's you'd need to create a complete new set of icons.
3. The positioning is  currently defined by vp.x a # & vp.y a #, not sure that more than 4 could be defined as never tried based on above.

Here I patch unity to work for 1x4 (cube,rotate) ws's only, that was pretty easy as it's just redefining which icon for which vp.x/.y & which pattern, I choose -

1 2

3 4

instead of

1 2

4 3

So that's quite doable, what you ask for not so.

Comment: Ok, say I want to create a new set of icons , where should I change which icon the launcher should use for each workspace?

Comment: Here's my current patch to set up for 1x4 workspace layout, maybe you can glean from that. https://paste.ubuntu.com/23458502/

Comment: Thank you! Let's hope I can come up with something useful from this.